# На каком этапе защищаться от xss: Api или Front?

Tags: api, frontend, backend, xss

Есть сайт, на котором начали добавлять модули front (на angular) и api (php).
Встал вопрос, а на каком уровне лучше защищаться от xss? Разработчики бэка и фронта переводят друг на друга.

Доводы в этом вопросе (B = back, api, F = front):

1. B: api должна передовать то что ей передали и не искажать данные.
   Защищаться должна только от прямого нарушения работоспособности api.
2. B: с api могут работать не только web технологии, которым может
   быть безраличны теги, но чувствительна к другим уязвимостям, которые
   могут исказить работу web. Т.е. api не должна подстраиваться под
   всех клиентов, с которыми она работает.
3. F: front должен работать
   с данными которые пришл
4. F: по api должны передаваться чистые
   данные без html тегов

Answer (score 1):

Приложение на фронте выполняется под управление пользовательского компьютера и теоретически этот пользователь может делать с ним всё, что захочет. В том числе вообще минуя фронт отправлять запросы напрямую к API, только куки подставить. Взять какой-нибудь Telerik Fiddler и вперед. Поэтому защита встраивается на бек, а не отдается на откуп того, что пользователь не в состоянии сломать фронт. Так же работает валидация, её встраивают на беке, даже если на фронте она есть и дублируется.

Так же по последнему комментарию, никто не запрещает передавать через API всякие HTML теги, типичный пример в WYSIWYG редакторах. Просто их надо фильтровать, вырезая всякие XSS-подозрительные теги на типа `<script>` или `<iframe>` во время записи.

Comment: Всё это конечно правильно, но к XSS не имеет отношения. Где фильтровать теги - нет большого значения.

Comment: @andreymal, почему, если фронт не может гарантировать безопасность попадающего в API текста, который будет впоследствии отображен другим пользователям? При этом возможно даже не в этой же самой системе.

Comment: Злоумышленник никак не может вмешаться в правильно реализованный фронт, поэтому он отлично отфильтрует пришедший из API текст, всё гарантирует и беспокоиться не о чем. Если же юзер сам полезет своими шаловливыми ручками в devtools — это проблемы только этого юзера, а не фронта.